# VNC clients with Snow Leopard support

Tags: 11.10, mac, remote-desktop, vnc, macosx

I am looking for a good VNC client to use with Snow Leopard.

Vinagre works, but is not flexible, and thus slow. I tried a couple other ones, but they failed to connect. (Incompatible protocol or security, or something to that effect.)

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to connect from Leopard to Windows 7 i'd suggest to use - OnlineVNC.
 It use Web browser to acces to the VNC Server.

Safari is fully supported. http://www.onlinevnc.com